# Need Clarification in trigger

Tags: trigger

I am writing the trigger in after update in order object, the trigger should work only for  first time only, Is it Possible to restrict the trigger? If anyone Knows Guide me for the Answer

Trigger code:

```
 Trigger AutoEmailsending on Order (after update) 
    {
        Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
        Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
        for(order or1 : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(or1.Status == 'Submitted' && (or1.Subtype__c =='Offer' || or1.Subtype__c =='ASP'))
            {
                Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
                Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
            }
        }
        List<Attachment> Attachmentlst = [Select Id,
                                                 ParentId, 
                                                 Name,
                                                 BodyLength,
                                                 Body,
                                                 Description 
                                            From Attachment 
                                            where ParentId=:Orderdetail.keyset()];
        Map<Id,Account> Accountmap = New Map<Id,account>([Select id,
                                                                 Name,
                                                                 Email_Address__c,
                                                                 Market__c,
                                                                 JDE_ship_to_account_no__c 
                                                            from account
                                                            where id in:accountid]);
        Map<String, Blob> resources = new Map<String, Blob>();
        for(StaticResource resource:[SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource where Name IN ('TC_for_France','TC_for_Italy')]) 
        {
            resources.put(resource.Name, resource.Body);
        }
        User currentUser = [Select Id,Phone,name from User where Id =:System.UserInfo.getUserId()];

        for (attachment attachmentlst1 : attachmentlst )
        {
            List<String> Toaddress = new List<String>();
            List<String> CCaddress = new List<String>(); 
            String Orderid = attachmentlst1.ParentId;
            String ResourceName;
            String TCname;
            string  strHtmlBody;

            String Emailaddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
            String CustomerServiceEmail =         Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Customer_Service_Email__c;
            string SellingOfficePhone =         Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Selling_Office_Phone__c;
            String OrderNumber = Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).OrderNumber;

            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List <Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
            if(Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Email_Address__c != null)
            {
                Toaddress.add(Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Email_Address__c);
            }
            String Market = Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Market__c;
            CCaddress.add(emailaddress);
            if(CustomerServiceEmail !=null)
            CCaddress.add(CustomerServiceEmail);

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setToAddresses(Toaddress);
            mail.setCcAddresses(CCaddress);
            if(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).Subtype__c =='Offer' || Market=='FR')
            {
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-FR'); 
                ResourceName = 'TC_for_France';
                TCname = 'CONDITIONS_GENERALES_DEVENTE.pdf';

            }
            else
            {
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-IT');
                ResourceName = 'TC_for_Italy';
                TCname = 'Condizioni_generali_di_vendita.pdf';

                mail.setSubject('ORDINE ONETOUCH           '+(AccountMap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Name));
               }

            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
            efa.setFileName(attachmentlst1.Name);
            efa.setBody(attachmentlst1.Body);
            fileAttachments.add(efa);
            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
            efa1.setFileName(TCname);
            efa1.setBody(resources.get(resourceName));
            fileAttachments.add(efa1);
            mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: in before update check for lastmodifiedDate and createdDate and if they are same then this might be first time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check something like

```
Trigger AutoEmailsending on Order (before update) 
    {
        Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
        Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
        for(order or1 : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(or1.Status == 'Submitted' && (or1.Subtype__c =='Offer' || or1.Subtype__c =='ASP') && or1.createdDate == Trigger.Oldmap.get(or1.id).LastmodifiedDate)
            {
                // remaining part continue
```

Just add a extra condition `or1.createdDate == Trigger.Oldmap.get(or1.id).LastmodifiedDate` and it might help you.

Comment: In after update created Date will Not be Null,How to overcome this Scenario@Tusharsharma

Comment: if you want to run only when record create then you can run it on after insert. Or you can create a custom checkbox field and set it to true. next run if checkbox is true then don't run the trigger.

Comment: @user36188 instead of downvoting it would be better if you don't delete your comment and make your requirement more clear.

Comment: Till Now I am not devoted to anyone , when i am started using stackexchange for the past  1 1/2 Years, Anyanswer for my Question I welcomed and Upvaoted only

Comment: @user36188 you have deleted all your comments so I thought you did that. If your requirement is still not completed provide more details I would be happy to help.

Comment: why should i want to do? you are helping  and Guiding Me for the Answer

Comment: atlast I came to your point creating the checkbox field , can you please check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152701/process-builder?noredirect=1#comment223596_152701 @Tushar Sharma

Comment: if i update the checkbox field values in triggers, i have to use Update Keyword, then order object I have so many after update triggers are there, so I came to Process Builder @Tushar Sharma

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152669/trigger-in-salesforce?noredirect=1#comment223542_152669 @Tushar sharma

Answer (score 0):

Is your trigger getting called twice in the same transaction? If so, i think you are running into recursive triggers situation. And for that you would want to use static variable.

Example:

```
public class checkTriggerStatus {
   public static boolean fireTrigger = true;
}
```

your trigger should use this to check if this is first run

```
trigger trig on Order (After update){
  if (checkTriggerStatus.fireTrigger){
      // your code here
      // set fireTrigger to false to avoid recursion
       checkTriggerStatus.fireTrigger = false;
   }
}
```

More details can be found @ https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm