# Trigger in salesforce

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger code:

```
 Trigger AutoEmailsending on Order (after update) 
    {
        Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
        Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
        for(order or1 : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(or1.Status == 'Submitted' && (or1.Subtype__c =='Offer' || or1.Subtype__c =='ASP'))
            {
                Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
                Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
            }
        }
        List<Attachment> Attachmentlst = [Select Id,
                                                 ParentId, 
                                                 Name,
                                                 BodyLength,
                                                 Body,
                                                 Description 
                                            From Attachment 
                                            where ParentId=:Orderdetail.keyset()];
        Map<Id,Account> Accountmap = New Map<Id,account>([Select id,
                                                                 Name,
                                                                 Email_Address__c,
                                                                 Market__c,
                                                                 JDE_ship_to_account_no__c 
                                                            from account
                                                            where id in:accountid]);
        Map<String, Blob> resources = new Map<String, Blob>();
        for(StaticResource resource:[SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource where Name IN ('TC_for_France','TC_for_Italy')]) 
        {
            resources.put(resource.Name, resource.Body);
        }
        User currentUser = [Select Id,Phone,name from User where Id =:System.UserInfo.getUserId()];

        for (attachment attachmentlst1 : attachmentlst )
        {
            List<String> Toaddress = new List<String>();
            List<String> CCaddress = new List<String>(); 
            String Orderid = attachmentlst1.ParentId;
            String ResourceName;
            String TCname;
            string  strHtmlBody;

            String Emailaddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
            String CustomerServiceEmail =         Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Customer_Service_Email__c;
            string SellingOfficePhone =         Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Selling_Office_Phone__c;
            String OrderNumber = Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).OrderNumber;

            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List <Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
            if(Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Email_Address__c != null)
            {
                Toaddress.add(Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Email_Address__c);
            }
            String Market = Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Market__c;
            CCaddress.add(emailaddress);
            if(CustomerServiceEmail !=null)
            CCaddress.add(CustomerServiceEmail);

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setToAddresses(Toaddress);
            mail.setCcAddresses(CCaddress);
            if(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).Subtype__c =='Offer' || Market=='FR')
            {
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-FR'); 
                ResourceName = 'TC_for_France';
                TCname = 'CONDITIONS_GENERALES_DEVENTE.pdf';

            }
            else
            {
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-IT');
                ResourceName = 'TC_for_Italy';
                TCname = 'Condizioni_generali_di_vendita.pdf';

                mail.setSubject('ORDINE ONETOUCH           '+(AccountMap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Name));
               }

            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
            efa.setFileName(attachmentlst1.Name);
            efa.setBody(attachmentlst1.Body);
            fileAttachments.add(efa);
            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
            efa1.setFileName(TCname);
            efa1.setBody(resources.get(resourceName));
            fileAttachments.add(efa1);
            mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
        }
    }
```

I have another trigger code:

```
trigger AutoAttachmentSend on Attachment (after insert) 
{
    Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
    Set<Id> Parentid = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
    for(Attachment Att : Trigger.new)
    {
        Parentid.add (Att.ParentId);
    }
    List <Order> Orderlst = [Select Id, 
                                    Accountid,
                                    Status,
                                    OrderNumber,
                                    Subtype__C
                               From Order 
                               where id in:Parentid 
                               AND (Subtype__c ='Offer' OR Subtype__c ='ASP') 
                               AND Status ='Submitted'];
    for(Order or1: Orderlst)
    {
        Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
        Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
    }
    List<Attachment> Attachmentlst = [Select Id,
                                             ParentId, 
                                             Name,
                                             BodyLength,
                                             Body,
                                             Description 
                                        From Attachment 
                                        where ParentId=:Orderdetail.keyset()];
    Map<Id,Account> Accountmap = New Map<Id,account>([Select id,
                                                             Name,
                                                             Email_Address__c,
                                                             Market__c,
                                                             JDE_ship_to_account_no__c 
                                                        from account
                                                        where id in:accountid]);
    Map<String, Blob> resources = new Map<String, Blob>();
    for(StaticResource resource:[SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource where Name IN ('TC_for_France','TC_for_Italy')]) 
    {
        resources.put(resource.Name, resource.Body);
    }
    User currentUser = [Select Id,Phone,name from User where Id =:System.UserInfo.getUserId()];

    for (attachment attachmentlst1 : attachmentlst )
    {
        List<String> Toaddress = new List<String>();
        List<String> CCaddress = new List<String>(); 
        String Orderid = attachmentlst1.ParentId;
        String ResourceName;
        String TCname;
        string  strHtmlBody;

        String Emailaddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        String CustomerServiceEmail = Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Customer_Service_Email__c;
        String SellingOfficePhone = Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Selling_Office_Phone__c;
        String OrderNumber = Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).OrderNumber;

        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List <Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

        String Market = Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Market__c;
        CCaddress.add(emailaddress);
        if(CustomerServiceEmail !=null)
        CCaddress.add(CustomerServiceEmail);


        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(Toaddress);
        mail.setCcAddresses(CCaddress);
        if(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).Subtype__c =='Offer' || Market=='FR')
        {
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-FR'); 
            ResourceName = 'TC_for_France';
            TCname = 'CONDITIONS_GENERALES_DEVENTE.pdf';

        }
        else
        {
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-IT');
            ResourceName = 'TC_for_Italy';
            TCname = 'Condizioni_generali_di_vendita.pdf';


        }

        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa.setFileName(attachmentlst1.Name);
        efa.setBody(attachmentlst1.Body);
        fileAttachments.add(efa);
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa1.setFileName(TCname);
        efa1.setBody(resources.get(resourceName));
        fileAttachments.add(efa1);
        mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
    }
}
```

**

> **order is the Parent Object and Attachment is the Child Object,after creating the order with the attachment and mail should go to the users
>   are Mentioned in the code,I want to execute the Trigger for first time
>   only that is order creation,Next time editing record, the mail should not
>   go,How? Can Anyone Guide me for the Answer , what i have to add
>   conditon in trigger code to restrict the email for second time**

**
 what I have to add conditions like `or1.createdDate == Trigger.Oldmap.get(or1.id).LastmodifiedDate` to restrict trigger for second time  like in the code

it is possible to add `attachment.created Date== order.CreatedDate` if I use this condition also same time for the user second time also mail will go

Two Scenario:

> > An order status is draft and attachment is there then the order status is submitted mail will go from order trigger
>
> An order status is submitted and attachment is there then the mail
>   will go from attachment trigger
>
> A order without Attachment mail will not Go thats all

My question

> If I edit the order second time the mail will not go the user How?

Comment: You could always add something like a checkbox that is not displayed on the page layout and is set by the trigger after the send. As an aside wouldn't it be better to create an Order Trigger methods class and put all the shared code in that and call it from the triggers to cut down the amount of code you need to maintain?

Comment: If you are using before trigger then update the checkbox from the same trigger without any issue.

Comment: Instead of just asking simple basic question it would be better if you try your hand in code.  When you update checkbox in attachment trigger then in order trigger in first condition you are checking checkbox == false. Which you will not get so it will not allow your trigger to run recursive.

Comment: @TusharSharma it is possible to update value in  the locked record

Comment: @TusharSharma http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152945/record-lock-release?noredirect=1#comment224105_152945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing. Create a checkbox field Mail sent on order. Now if you sent mail from order then update this field or if you sent email from Attachment Trigger then with order status update it as well.

Now in your code you can easily do this check

```
Trigger AutoEmailsending on Order (after update) 
    {
        Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
        Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
        for(order or1 : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(or1.Status == 'Submitted' && (or1.Subtype__c =='Offer' || or1.Subtype__c =='ASP') && !or1.Email_Sent__c)
            {
                 or1.Email_Sent__c = true; //update here
```

and in Attachment Trigger

```
List <Order> Orderlst = [Select Id, 
                                    Accountid,
                                    Status,
                                    OrderNumber,
                                    Subtype__C, Email _Sent__c
                               From Order 
                               where id in:Parentid 
                               AND (Subtype__c ='Offer' OR Subtype__c ='ASP') 
                               AND Status ='Submitted'];
    for(Order or1: Orderlst)
    {
       if(!or1.Email_Sent__c){
        or1.Email_Sent__c = true; //update here
        Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
        Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
      }
    }
update Orderlst;
```

This will not send recursive emails.

Comment: @user36188 you don't need to perform update thats why I am asking you to use before update. You can update from first for loop. Default it will be false.

Comment: @user36188 in Trigger.new you will get updated value in both and after trigger.

Comment: @user36188 yes you can also on side note you should read about triggers and there event.

Comment: @user36188 I have added code for Order object. You can use same thing in event.

Comment: @user36188 In attachment when you update order status also update this checkbox

Comment: @user36188 I have updated my answer.